# Initialize a Container of unique_ptr with iota

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, iota

To learn about the intricacies of C++11 I am playing aroung with `unique_ptr` a bit.

I wonder, is there any way to use `iota` to initialize an Container of `unique_ptr`?

I started with the unique-ptr-less solution which works fine:

```
std::vector<int> nums(98); // 98 x 0
std::iota(begin(nums), end(alleZahlen), 3); // 3..100
```

Now lets do it as far as we can using `unique_ptr`

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> nums(98); // 98 x nullptr
std::unique_ptr three{ new int{3} };
std::iota(begin(nums), end(nums), std::move{three});
```

This fails obviously. Reasons:

- Although I marked `three` with `move` as a `&&` this may not be sufficient to copy/move the initial value into the container.
- `++initValue` will also not work, because `initValue` is of type `unique_ptr<int>`, and there is no `operator++` defined. But: we could define a free function `unique_ptr<int> operator++(const unique_ptr<int>&);` and that would take care of that at least.
- But to copy/move the results from that operation is again not permitted in `unique_ptr` and this time I can not see how I could trick the compiler into using `move`.

Well, that's where I stopped. And I wonder if I miss some interesting idea on how to tell the compiler that he may `move` the results of the `operator++`. Or are there other hindrances, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to end up with 98 instances of `unique_ptr`, there must be 98 calls to `new`. You attempt to get away with just one - that can't possibly fly.

If you are really intent on pounding a square peg into a round hole, you could do [something like this](http://ideone.com/gvssz9):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class MakeIntPtr {
public:
  explicit MakeIntPtr(int v) : value_(v) {}
  operator std::unique_ptr<int>() {
    return std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(value_));
  }
  MakeIntPtr& operator++() { ++value_; return *this; }
private:
  int value_;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> nums(98);
  std::iota(begin(nums), end(nums), MakeIntPtr(3));

  std::cout << *nums[0] << ' ' << *nums[1] << ' ' << *nums[2];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I admit, it's like you said "square peg into a round hole", for learning stuff. Good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) is a better algorithm for this?

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;
{
    v.reserve(98);
    int n = 2;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 98,
                    [&n]() { return std::make_unique<int>(++n); });
}
```

Comment: Nice code, and it's much more practical then my theoretical question. But I was thinking about `iota` specifically.